# Python photo animation trouble

Tags: python, tkinter, python-imaging-library

im trying to make an image scroll across the screen until it gets to the middle and stops. How can I achieve this? Im using python 2.7 with tkinter and the PIL lib.

Thanks for the help!!!

Comment: It is generally appreciated if you post some of the snippets you tried already. I would recommend using something like `pygame` which makes this trivially easy. Not sure why you use PIL then :o

Comment: oh sorry about that. Im using PIL because I thought it was the only way I could get image files into Python. I find it particularly weird, can I also achieve this with pygame?

Answer (score 1):

It's certainly possible with good old tkinter! This should work, haven't been able to test the PIL stuff but I tested it without. Press the left key to move the image.

```
from Tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk

class App:
    def __init__(self,master):
        self.xRes = 500
        self.yRes = 500
        master.geometry(str(self.xRes)+"x"+str(self.yRes))
        #if you didnt have PIL (gif only): myImage = PhotoImage(file="image.gif") 
        myImage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("image.jpg")) 
        self.photoFrame = Label(master,image = myImage,width = 300, height = 300)
        self.photoFrame.place(x=-310, y=0)
        self.photoFrame.image = myImage
        self.photoFrame.focus_set()
        self.photoFrame.bind("<Left>",self.animate)


    def moveImage1(self):
        cur = int(self.photoFrame.place_info()["x"])
        pWidth = str(self.photoFrame.cget("width"))
        print(pWidth)
        while cur != (self.xRes/2) - (int(pWidth)/2):
            cur = int(self.photoFrame.place_info()["x"])
            self.photoFrame.place(x=cur+2, y=0)
            print(cur)
            root.update()


    def animate(self,event):
        self.moveImage1()

root = Tk()
app = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

If you wanted to add more animations, you would build up more methods like moveImage1, one for each animation. Then, just call them how you like. The method gets the current x position of the Label widget, then increments it by 2. Then, root.update() is called to refresh the window. Let me know if you need anything extra.

Comment: instead of a while loop, you can use `after` to move the image one unit, then have the method use `after` to schedule itself to run again in a few dozen milliseconds, depending on how fast you want it to move.

Comment: true! I'm not sure it needs it, tkinter can't move images awfully fast

Comment: What do you mean it can't move images fast? How fast do you need it to be? I can move it as many pixels as you want every couple of milliseconds or so. You can probably get 60fps or more for simple animations.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, but when I paste this code in and add my own image file there is nothing in the window. Am I doing something wring?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of an image that moves from the left to the center of a canvas:

```
import Tkinter as tk

imagedata = '''
    R0lGODlhEAAQAMQZAMPDw+zs7L+/v8HBwcDAwLW1teLi4t7e3uDg4MLCwuHh4e7u7t/f38TExLa2
    tre3t7i4uL6+vu/v77q6uu3t7b29vby8vLm5ubu7u+3t7QAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAEA
    ABkALAAAAAAQABAAAAWNYCaOZFlWV6pWZlZhTQwAyYSdcGRZGGYNE8vo1RgYCD2BIkK43DKXRsQg
    oUQiFAkCI3iILgCLIEvJBiyQiOML6GElVcsFUllD25N3FQN51L81b2ULARN+dhcDFggSAT0BEgcQ
    FgUicgQVDHwQEwc+DxMjcgITfQ8Pk6AlfBEVrjuqJhMOtA4FBRctuiUhADs=
'''

class Example(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self)
        self.canvas.pack(side="bottom", fill="both", expand=True)

        self.image = tk.PhotoImage(data=imagedata)
        image_id = self.canvas.create_image(0,0, anchor="nw", image=self.image)

        self.move_to_center(image_id)

    def move_to_center(self, id):
        (x0,y0) = self.canvas.coords(id)
        if x0 < int(self.canvas.winfo_width()/2):
            self.canvas.move(id, 1,0)
        self.after(10, lambda id=id: self.move_to_center(id))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    Example(root).pack(fill="both", expand=True)
    root.mainloop()
```